# PM2 startup on macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina

I'm trying to set pm2 to auto start on Mac OS like this `pm2 startup`

However I keep getting this error: 
`env: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory`

I tried the suggestion from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664282/how-to-use-pm2-startup-command-on-mac But the even using this command I keep getting the same error: `pm2 startup darwin`

How can I get pm2 to startup automatically on Mac OS Catalina?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that pm2 isn't generating the correct script because your `PATH` variable contains spaces (most likely "VMWare Fusion" in your case).

Run `echo $PATH`, clean it up by escaping the space character using a backslash (\), then manually paste the resulting `PATH` variable in pm2's generated startup script.

So basically instead of running a generated pm2 script like this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u <user> --hp <user_folder>
```

run something like this:

```
sudo env PATH=<your `echo $PATH` output with escaped spaces>:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u <user> --hp <user_folder>
```

Comment: It'd be better to use the `PATH` variable directly, but double-quote it to prevent trouble with spaces etc. Something like: `sudo env PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin" /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup launchd -u <user> --hp <user_folder>`